# pasar ruta laravel a través de una promisse JS

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Buenas estoy aprendiendo laravel y a la vez JS poco a poco, necesito ayuda de alguien que sepa como se pasan o si es posible pasar rutas que tengo definidas. o bien ayudarme a decirme como se debe realizar.

hice una vista que realiza todas las acciones de un CRUD hasta ahí todo bien, pero al hacer el filtrado por fechas lo hago mediante una promise de la siguiente manera

```
$(document).ready(function () {

const $fechaIni    = document.getElementById('fechaIni') 
const $fechaFin    = document.getElementById('fechaFin')

  $("#buscar").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


   if ($fechaIni.value == '' || $fechaFin.value == '') {
     alert("campos de fechas no pueden estar vacios");
   }else{
      fetch( `http://sisvet.test/AgendaCita/${$fechaIni.value}/${$fechaFin.value}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
          let output = '';
          
          response.forEach(element => {
            output += `<tr>
             <td>${element.mascota.nombre_mascota}</td> 
             <td>${element.mascota.propietario.nombre}</td> 
             <td>${element.mascota.propietario.telefono1}</td> 
             <td>${element.mascota.propietario.correo}</td> 
             <td> ${element['motivo']}</td> 
             <td> ${element['fecha_cita']}</td> 
             <td> ${element['hora_cita']}</td> 
             <td>
             <a href="{{aqui va la ruta eliminar}}" type="text" title="Eliminar Cita" class="btn btn-danger eliminar-menu " ><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            </td> 
             </tr>`;

          });
          document.querySelector('.tbody').innerHTML = output;
          $fechaIni.value = ''; 
          $fechaFin.value = ''; 
      }).catch(error => console.log(error));
   }
    })
});
```

Donde indique en el código {{aquí va la ruta}} es donde necesito que vaya a la ruta de eliminar y haga las operaciones del controlador que estoy llamando por esa ruta. si pongo la ruta como lo hago en blade no funciona de hecho tengo una clase llamada dentro de la etiqueta  "eliminar-menu" que muestra un sweet alert pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: ¿Y esa ruta que necesitas insertar en tu código depende de qué condiciones o variables?¿No puedes enviar la ruta como parte de la respuesta?

Comment: la ruta que necesito enviar es la siguiente {{route('eliminar_agendaCita',$agenda->id)}}